# Is there a way to display data based on login name?

Tags: c#, html

I want to have it to where when users log in they can only see the information from the table based on their email.

I am extremely new at coding and have done most of this from scratch but cannot seem to figure out how resolve this issue I am working on.

Currently I am using the `@user.identity.name` for their email when a new form is submitted. Any help would be great! thank you.

Index Page

```
@model IEnumerable<WebApplication1.Models.Ticket>

@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Index";
}

<h1>Tickets</h1>

<p>
    <a asp-action="Create">Create New</a>
</p>
<table class="table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Email)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Phone)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Date)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Location)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Severity)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Issue)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Details)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Viewed)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Resolved)
            </th>
            <th></th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
@foreach (var item in Model) {
        <tr>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Email)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Phone)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Date)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Location)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Severity)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Issue)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Details)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Viewed)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Resolved)
            </td>
            <td>
                <a asp-action="Edit" asp-route-id="@item.EmployeeID">Edit</a> |
                <a asp-action="Details" asp-route-id="@item.EmployeeID">Details</a> |
                <a asp-action="Delete" asp-route-id="@item.EmployeeID">Delete</a>
            </td>
        </tr>
}
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Ticket Model

```
namespace WebApplication1.Models
{
    public class Ticket
    {
        [Key]
        public int EmployeeID { get; set; }
        [Column(TypeName ="varchar(50)")]
        public string Email { get; set; }
        [Column(TypeName = "varchar(50)")]
        [Required(ErrorMessage ="This field is required.")]
        public string Phone { get; set; }
        [Column(TypeName = "varchar(50)")]
        public string Date { get; set; }
        [Column(TypeName = "varchar(50)")]
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "This field is required.")]
        public string Location { get; set; }
        [Column(TypeName = "varchar(50)")]
        public string Severity { get; set; }
        [Column(TypeName = "varchar(50)")]
        [Required(ErrorMessage ="This field is required.")]
        public string Issue { get; set; }
        [Column(TypeName = "varchar(Max)")]
        public string Details { get; set; }
        [Column(TypeName = "varchar(50)")]
        public string Viewed { get; set; }
        [Column(TypeName = "varchar(50)")]
        public string Resolved { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: This is typically handled in the controller, were you fill the model. Can you post that part?

Comment: add to Stenfan's point. This is usually done w/ identity scope claim or roles. Spend couple days to read about this. Will take some time so dont rush

Comment: Interesting like I said I am extremely new at this and just trying to work through it to learn something but I will look into Identity scope claim and roles. A week ago I knew nothing about coding so I am just learning as I go.